# youtube freezing videos in fresh 22.04 installation

Tags: firefox, chromium, youtube, 22.04

I recently installed ubuntu 22.04 fresh installations on intel NUC 's intel-i5 D5420WYK with no sound, no video on youtube (freezing). Tried ubuntu extras and login sesion as xorg config :(

Tried in Chromium, Firefox, and Google Chrome, if you try to see a video, a circle rounding starts and never ends (like loading)
Any ideas will be appreciated

Comment: Bandwidth issue? Test with `speedtest`. Last drivers? `sudo ubuntu-drivers install`. Fully upgraded? Tried a live instance? Add the output of `inxi -SAG`

Comment: WiFi connection? What's your MTU? You can find your MTU with `ip link`. Read `man ip ip-link`.

Comment: I tried all answers without success.

Comment: I tried all answers without success. ==>> The problem is on Intel Hasswel and the sound component. By default uses pulseaudio. If you change to xorg and change to Pipewire to replace PulseAudio it works fine including obs, youtube and vlc recording audio. Thanks to Ji M in his good article: https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/04/pipewire-replace-pulseaudio-ubuntu-2204/

Answer (score 3):

The problem is on Intel Hasswel and the sound component. By default uses PulseAudio.

If you change to XOrg and change to Pipewire to replace PulseAudio, the video works fine, including obs, YouTube and VLC recording audio.

Thanks to Ji M in his good article: https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/04/pipewire-replace-pulseaudio-ubuntu-2204/

Comment: I am am having the issue as well. AMD GPU. It fixes if I switch pulseaudio output elsewhere and back.

Comment: For me, the issue happens when I have my headphones connected via USB. When I plug it out, it is still connected via BlueTooth, and Youtube starts playing. Very weird. Thanks!